# How to use increase dimension for MNIST dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-resizing, mnist

I try to use the MNIST dataset for Alexnet with Keras, so I should change dimension(because MNIST is gray-scale, Alexnet needs to be RGB and also 227*227). Now I get some results, `numpy_imgs=(10,227,227,1)` but I should do this like `(10,227,227,3)` you can see what I did before in my code,
thank you.

```
  import tensorflow as tf
  import numpy as np
  from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
  batch=mnist.train.next_batch(10)
  X_batch = batch[0]
  batch_tensor = tf.reshape(X_batch, [10, 28, 28, 1])
  resized_images = tf.image.resize_images(batch_tensor, [227,227])
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      numpy_imgs = resized_images.eval(session=sess) # mnist images converted to numpy array

  r2=[]
  t=list(numpy_imgs)
  dim = np.zeros((227,227))
  for i in range(0,10):
      R=np.stack((t[i],dim,dim),axis=2)
      R=list(R)
      r2.append(R)
  y3=np.asarray(r2)
```

I tried something below but got an error like "ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape", how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile) which repeat a tensor along one of its dimension:

```
y3 = tf.tile(numpy_imgs, (1, 1, 1, 3))
```

If you want to complete it with zeroed tensors, you should use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) (or [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) instead of `stack`.

```
dim = np.zeros((227, 227, 2))
for i in range(0, 10):
    R = np.concatenate((t[i], dim), axis=2)
    ...
```

You can even do it more concisely, treating all batch at once:

```
dim = np.zeros((10, 227, 227, 2))
y3 = np.concatenate((numpy_imgs, dim), axis=3
```

Here is a more general example:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    i = np.random.random((10, 227, 227, 1))
    dim = np.zeros((10, 227, 227, 2))
    print(i.shape)
    print(dim.shape)
    print(np.concatenate((i, dim), axis=3).shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
(10, 227, 227, 1)
(10, 227, 227, 2)
(10, 227, 227, 3)
```